# How to Handle Fragmentation in Boost's managed_shared_memory

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

Cross posted on [Boost Dev mailing list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Need-urgent-help-gt-gt-How-to-Handle-Fragmentation-in-Boost-s-managed-shared-memory-td4698104.html)

I am using Boost::managed_shared_memory for my project. For allocate and deallocate we are using boost APIs as show in below example:

```
shm_controller.reset(new boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory( boost::interprocess::open_or_create, shmName, size));
void * addr = shm_controller->allocate(size) ;
shm_controller ->deallocate(addr);
```

For this I have two question:

1. How can i handle fragmentation in this ? We are doing very frequent allocation and release.
2. What kind of allocation we are using in boost (slab, slub, slob) ?

First question is very important for me.

Please let me know if you want more info on any of these.